# Using vlookup to return adjacent column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to use a vlookup to get the values of the Grade column in sheet3 to sheet1 based on matching employeeId. I have attached my sheet. I realize I have duplicates in sheet1 but i have a reason for having that and i want to keep it that way.

The formula i have used seems to be working but down the line, like for ID 10625 i see 0 as grade where it should actually give J. What am i missing? An alternate solution is welcome too.

Sheet1 data

```
employeeId
10893
10890
10890
10890
10890
10890
10890
10891
10891
10891
10891
10891
10891
10877
10877
10877
```

Sheet3 data

```
employeeId  Grade
10589        K 
10590        H 
10591        I 
10592        H 
10593        G
```

Formula used,

```
Formula =VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet3!A:B,1,FALSE)
```

Thank you

[Excel File](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sx5Zsg2bJikyP8-V_aIlnc9wtvMlEmpG?usp=sharing)

Comment: the excel file is private, can you add your current formula. cannot help if can't see the formula or the data.

Comment: @Jpsh Can you retry to access the file? I have added some sample data to the question as well

Comment: Seems to me you just need `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet3!A:B,2,FALSE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're writing the `VLOOKUP` once and dragging it down, this is offsetting your values so you'll want to use `$` to lock the rows so they're not offset by dragging

you can use this and avoid the issue

`=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet3!A:B,2,FALSE)`

or do this to lock the column and row

`=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet3!A:B,1,FALSE),Sheet3!$B$2)`